# c# Dynamic.Linq - groupby and then select by condition

Tags: c#, linq

I thought it'll be easy but i'm really struggling with this.

I have a Table with this schema:
Name, Date, Value

Here's what I'm trying to achive:

1. group all rows by 'Name'
2. from that group, select the 'Value' which it's 'Date' is the
   biggest

The #1 was easily achieved by GroupBy("Name","it")
but, now what...?
How do i query the grouped results???

Thank you all.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. i think i learned something... the "converting to Dynamic.Linq Task" of those queries is the next task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the assumptions I've made from your question is "Date is the biggest" you mean the latest one for each.

```
var data = new List<Data>
                             {
                                 new Data() {Name = "one3", Date = new DateTime(2001, 11, 11), Value = 7},
                                 new Data() {Name = "one2", Date = new DateTime(2001, 11, 11), Value = 111},
                                 new Data() {Name = "one2", Date = new DateTime(2011, 11, 11), Value = 7},
                             };

var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(grouping => grouping.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

I'm sure there is probably a better way of doing the linq query but I hope this at least points you in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that, for each Name, you want the Value of the record which has the most recent Date for that Name. If this is correct, then the following should work

```
from d in new[]
{
    new { Name = "x", Date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), Value = 1, },
    new { Name = "x", Date = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), Value = 2, },
    new { Name = "y", Date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), Value = 3, },
}
    group d by d.Name into g
    let maxDate = g.Max(d => d.Date)
    select new { Name = g.Key, Date = maxDate, Value = g.Single(p => p.Date == maxDate).Value }
```

I've included the Date in the results in case it's also required.

Answer (score 0):

See
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx
and
http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx

---

#### Update

Try this. It seems working for me:
I'm using a data from another answer. Hopefully this is not cheating...

```
var set = new[]
              {
                  new {Name = "x", Date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), Value = 1,},
                  new {Name = "x", Date = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), Value = 2,},
                  new {Name = "y", Date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), Value = 3,},
              };

var query =
    from x in set
    orderby x.Date descending
    group x by x.Name
    into g
    select g.First();

Console.WriteLine(query.First().Date);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but what i need is a specific query against a group results: i want a column value from the group results that match a specific condition.

Comment: I now read your query, and seriously cannot find a reason why you have to do it like this. Why not just apply the group on name, and max date?